# How can I remove Brackets from a String in scala?

Tags: arrays, string, scala

Here is my output of a scala program.

```
String = (44, 0, 22, -1)
```

Here is what i think, there are 4 values which are:
(44
 0
 22
 -1)

And the last 3 numbers have one space!

I want to do is to put the four numbers into a array, but how can I do that?

Comment: When I use .collect or .toArray. There is only one value in the Array. So maybe the String has only one value of (44, 0, 22, -1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filterNot` to remove parentheses and unwanted whitespace then `split` on comma as you would in Java to get an array of strings.

```
val s = "String = (44, 0, 22, -1)"

scala> s.filterNot(c => c  == '(' || c == ')' || c == ' ').split(",")
res2: Array[String] = Array(44, 0, 22, -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe...

```
"(44, 0, 22, -1)".split("[^-\\d]+").tail
```